# ASP.NET Identity duplicates tables with custom names

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I have a project in ASP.NET MVC 5 with .NET Framework and I'm using Identity to manage user authorization. The requirements of the project don't allow me to leave the default AspNet-(something) names in the database. Also, I need to add some custom attributes to roles and users. So I created a custom user and role class, like this:

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public virtual ICollection<RoleApllicationModel> RolesApplications { get; set; }
    public string description{get; set;}
}
```

With this class if I change the name of the table names like this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("SSO_USERS");
modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("SSO_ROLES");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("SSO_USER_LOGINS");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("SSO_USERS_ROLES");
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("SSO_USER_CLAIMS");
```

When it creates the database it adds a second table for Roles, one named `SSO_ROLES` and one `AspNetRoles`. The `aspnetroles` table has the `id` and `name` and the second has the `description` and a foreign key pointing to the `aspnetroles` table.

This doesn't make sense and I'd like to know if there's a way to avoid this behaviour to happen and only create the table `SSO_ROLES` with `id`, `name` and `description`. If I remove the description attributes, it only creates the `SSO_ROLES` table.

**Edit:**

Here's the context of Identity

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ApplicationModel> Applications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TokenModel> Tokens { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserApllicationModel> UsersApplications { get; set; }
    public DbSet<RoleApllicationModel> RolesApplications { get; set; }

    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        // Set the database intializer which is run once during application start
        // This seeds the database with admin user credentials and admin role
        Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("SSO_USUARIOS");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("SSO_ROLE");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("SSO_USUARIO_LOGINS");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("SSO_USUARIOS_ROLES");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("SSO_USUARIO_CLAIMS");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you concerned about the new table? Why do you want it in the existing table?

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the DbContext as it applies to these Identity Entities please?

Comment: Turner Bass, I added the dbcontext, thanks for the help. And mjwills, it adds unnecessary complexity to the database, and to create reports it makes a mess in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution if anyone deals with the same problem. You need to add to the modelBuilder the default Identity Class as well, like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("SSO_USERS");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("SSO_USERS");
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("SSO_ROLES");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("SSO_ROLES");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("SSO_USER_LOGINS");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("SSO_USERS_ROLES");
    modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("SSO_USER_CLAIMS");
}
```

If you are using a custom class like ApplicationRole, also add the original IdentityRole with the same table name.